# How to set up laravel sail to use sqlite on docker compose

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, laravel-sail

Firstly, is easy to set up laravel to use sail

```
composer require laravel/sail --dev

php artisan sail:install
```

The problem is, the docker compose is set to use mysql by default, but I actually need a sqlite.

sqlite is different right, since it use a file, so I super confuse on this

how do I set up laravel sail to works with sqlite instead of mysql?

Comment: Shouldn't need anything special. Just set it to use the SQLite DB_CONNECTION in the .env file. You may need to `touch database/database.sqlite` to create the initial empty file as well. What trouble are you having?

Comment: Exactly right. For mysql, etc, you'll need a service in your docker-compose.yml. for sqlite you don't need that special service, you just adjust your .env file and create your database

Comment: yes, it's right, but, what I'm trying to accomplish is that to make the sqlite live on the different container from my laravel app, so it's independent, not inside the laravel app itself. so when I shutdown the laravel container, the sqlite db it's fine

Comment: SQLite is intrinsically an embedded database: it doesn't have a separate server process and it can't run in a separate container.  That turns out to be a reason to avoid SQLite in container environments, since ideally you can run (multiple copies of) your application without keeping persistent state in the container(s) themselves.

Comment: @Amir If you shut down the Laravel container, the SQLite database **is** fine; it's still all right there in `database/database.sqlite`. Next time you start up the container it'll be all functional.